# Billing and the API

Tags: shopify, recurring-billing

I have hundreds of shops all subscribing to an App through 2 channels. Recurring and One Time payments. It seems that if a Shop accepts a recurring payment install, the shop is assigned a recurring charge entry. If the merchant then uninstalls the App and chooses to re-install it using the one-time charge, BOTH charges will exist for the shop and the App, even though they uninstalled from the recurring charge.

When a merchant uninstalls an App, can you assure me that indeed you remove all traces of previous charges. It seem not, as recently more than one client has approached me telling me that even though they accepted to pay a one-time charge, they still get prompted to pay the recurring charge too, based on a previous install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon app uninstall, all related app charges are cancelled.

Comment: Good to know. Now to figure out why merchants that accepted to pay a one time charge, get prompted to pay a recurring charge. My problem I am sure.

Comment: @Edward, after creating the recurring charge, I need to activate that or wait for trail ends(20 days). Please let me know as I am new to shopify